# How should i add data to a database in an application that implements Forms Security?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, database-design, ado.net

I am a bit newbie in ASP.NET and i don't really understand where should save some of the data that is related to my users.

Ill explain myself:

I use ASP 2.0 and i created a simple app that has registration and login mechanism. That data is stored in a DataBase that ASP automatically prepared for me (ASPNETDB.MDF) 
I see the following user related data in that database:

[image]

These are my doubts:

1. Can i add there another 3 columns for other data related to the user?
2. Should i create a new table within this database and link it to aspnet_Users with a FK?
3. Should i create a new database different than this one(This is just for security and similar stuff)?
4. If 3 is yes, how will i know witch row of data is related to witch user in the ASPNET.DB?

I am very confused, could someone tell me where should i store my other data related to user(age, city,bloodtype...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a seperate table if you want it to be easy. A lot of the user loading and saving is done through provider classes and you will probably tie yourself in knotts trying to customise all that.

If you are starting out, it's going to be better to create a seperate user table for extended detail on the user that you can access and edit at will.

Comment: You mean i need another table called users? Or another table called UserAttributes that i will link with a FK to the already existing aspnet_Users?(It is just for a homework, i need to make it easy. But i need the Already existing ASPNET.MDF)

Comment: I would go for the 2nd one of a different table. It really is a design issue more than a requirement so it's important you be comfortable with your choice.